# Unable to to get the SHA-1 fingerprint of the certificate using keytool

Tags: android, google-signin

I am following this guide to integrate google plus with my android app: [Start Integrating Google+ in your android app](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/getting-started)

When I try to run the the Keytool utility to get the SHA-1 fingerprint of the certificate, I get the output as follows: [image: Keytool Outout]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the arguments `-list -v` on the end of your keytool call. It should look like:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore <path-to-debug-or-production-keystore> -list -v
```